# C# list object value is in other type list/array

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a function in the list class that would allow me to select all the objects that have a

for example...

```
string [] names = {"matthew", "mark", "luke", "john"};
List<personObject> randomListOfPeople = generateRandomListOfPeople();
// suedo code start
List<personObject> allPeopleWithNamesinNamesArray = randomListOfPeople.Where( x => x.fname isin names)
// suedo code end

public class personObject
{
    public string fname {get; set;}
    public double height {get; set;}
    .....
}
```

I want to see where the list's names and the names array intersect.
the only way I could think of involves inner and outer loops, I'm trying to think of an alternative to that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Contains` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains(v=vs.100).aspx)) is your friend in these situations:

```
List<personObject> finalList = peopleList.Where( x => names.Contains(x.fname));
```

Comment: I forgot about .Contains. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join`

```
var allPeopleWithNamesinNamesArray = from p in randomListOfPeople
                                     join n in names on p.fname equals n
                                     select p;
```